# C program giving weird output

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am trying to copy certain parts of a string into other, new strings, but when i try to do it and print the results it gives me weird output.. I really hope someone can help. I have a feeling that it is something about missing pointers.. Here is my source;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void getData(char code[], char ware[], char prod[], char qual[])
{
    printf("Bar code: %s\n", code);

    /* Copy warehouse name from barcode */
    strncpy(ware, &code[0], 3);
    ware[4] = "\0";

    strncpy(prod, &code[3], 4);
    prod[5] = "\0";

    strncpy(qual, &code[7], 3);
    qual[4] = "\0";
}

int main(){

    /* allocate and initialize strings */
    char barcode[] = "ATL1203S14";
    char warehouse[4];
    char product[5];
    char qualifier[4];

    getData(&barcode, &warehouse, &product, &qualifier);

    /* print it */
    printf("Warehouse: %s\nID: %s\nQualifier: %s", warehouse, product, qualifier);

    return 0;
 }
```

EDIT:

The wierd output is:

```
Bar code: ATL1203S14
Warehouse: ATL
ID: ♫203(♫>
Qualifier: S14u♫203(♫>
```

Comment: And what is the "weird output"?

Comment: This is not the cause of your problem but instead of `getData(&barcode, &warehouse, &product, &qualifier);`, it would be more usual to write `getData(barcode, warehouse, product, qualifier);`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't thinking straight. I will add the wierd output now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you meant `'\0'` instead of `"\0"` and `3` instead of `4`:

```
ware[4] = "\0";
```

Try:

```
ware[3] = 0;
```

Also the `&` in `getData(&barcode, &warehouse...)` are useless. Just use `getData(barcode, warehouse...);`.

Comment: Thanks for all of you guys help. I finally got it fixed.. Thanks again

Comment: It's good to explain a bit why this is the correct answer, so other people and who post the question learn about it. You need to use ware[3] = 0; because 0 act as end-of-string character, and always remember that the array starts at 0 position, that's why its index 3 and not 4. The other problem, the call to getData() function is wrong because you need to pass pointers to it and char[] declares a pointer to a char array, so '&' is useless.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing past the end of the chars in your getData() function. You've defined `char product[5]`, which allocates 5 bytes of memory. That gives you array indexes 0,1,2,3,4. In getData, you write the product's null terminator to index 5, which is past the end of product, and will overwrite the next var's first character.

The same applies for barecode, warehouse, and qualifier.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that he isn't writing a null terminator, he's writing the address of a string that contains a null terminator.

Comment: How do I write a null terminator?

Comment: `x = \0` is proper, `x = "\0"` isn't.

Comment: @MarcB I think you meant either `x = '\0'` or `x = 0`, which would be equivalent.  `x = \0` will cause a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C and C++ are zero-based. The last index is one less than the length. You're setting a value in the memory *after* the array, for each of the arrays `ware, prod` and `qual`.

For example, instead of

```
 char warehouse[4];
 ware[4] = "\0";
```

you'd want:

```
 char warehouse[4];
 ware[3] = "\0";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getData(&barcode, &warehouse, &product, &qualifier);
```

This is not the way you should call `getData`. `getData` takes pointers, arrays are automatically converted to pointers, so theres no need to use the address-of operator `&`.

You should use

```
getData(barcode, warehouse, product, qualifier);
```

Comment: But at the same time, this is not the cause of the problem, just a stylistic issue.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: It's not a "stylistic issue", since it is a type error. Yet you are right, it doesn't cause OP's problems.

Answer (score 0):

The sizes of the strings inside main() don't include a place for the sentinel.

You need to have:

```
char warehouse[5];
char product[6];
char qualifier[5];
```

Also, You are assigning a pointer to the string "\0" into a character, where you should be assigning the character '\0' itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd do things a bit differently. In particular, `strncpy` is *almost* never really useful (I'm reasonably certain it was invented for file names in the original Unix FS, and while it fits their specific requirements quite nicely, those requirements are sufficiently unusual that it's rarely good for much of anything else).

Instead, I'd use sscanf: `sscanf(code, "%4c%5c%4c", ware, prod, qual);`

Your question does *not* make it clear whether this is really correct. As others have pointed out, you're writing past the ends of the space you've allocated. Above, I've assumed you specified the number of characters you want to copy, so you'd have to expand each of the allocations by one character to make room for the terminator. Alternative, if you've already left room for the terminator and want one fewer character copied, you'd have to reduce each of the lengths above by one so the format string would be "%3c%4c%3c".